# Smooth Manifolds- Question From Lee's Book

Tags: manifolds

I really need your help in understanding the following statement in the proof of the extension lemma in Lee's book:
Let $A \subseteq M^n $ be a closed submanifold of dimension $k$ , and let $F:A \to \mathbb{R} $ be a smooth function. We want to extend this function to the entire $M$ . THe problem is that I can't understand how to do it locally-
Let $ p \in A$ and let $ W_p $ be a neighborhood of $ p$ in $ M$ . I only know how to extend $F$ to a slice chart of $ p$ using projection . How can I do it for $ W_p$ ? The other problem is that the statement should also be true when $A$ is a closed subset of $M$, not necessarily a closed submanifold :(

i.e. how can I extend the function $F$ to a smooth function on $ W_p$ ?

Hope you'll be able to help me !

Thanks !

Comment: I assume, you are asking for smooth extension, I am assuming that $M$ is locally compact and hence $M$ admits Smooth partition of unity.

Comment: When $A$ is just an arbitrary closed subset of $M$, the statement follows from a partition of unity argument and [Whitney's extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem), which is a nontrivial result in harmonic analysis of Euclidean spaces. The submanifold case is much, much easier.

Comment: I'm not that sure about the Whitney's extension theorem, but thanks, I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure, if i understood you correctly: Please have following answer:

If $A \subset M^n$ manifold of $k$ dimension.For every point $p\in M$ there is a neighborhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $M$, if points of neighborhood of $U_p$ can be written as $(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ then  in sufficiently small neighborhood, we can think 
$$U_p\to A \text{,by}$$ 
$$p:(x_1,x_2,...x_n)\to (x_1,x_2,..x_k)$$ as submersion. 
Now consider $f \circ p: U\to \mathbb R$. This is a smooth map which is extension of $f$. Now **If $M$ has smooth partition of unity** $\phi$ subordinate to **(locally compact)** family $U_p$  , then we have extension of $f$ as $f.\phi$.

Comment: That's excatly what I was missing.
Thanks !